# How to update object in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update my object using `this.setState({dob.year: '1980'})` but this code doesn't work.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    dob: {
      'month' : 'January',
      'day' : '01',
      'year' : '2015'
  };
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` has no magic in it for expanding paths like `dob.year`. It just takes normal javascript objects. If you want to update a sub-state property without touching the rest of the object, you have to do it manually.

```
this.setState({dob: Object.assign({}, this.state.dob, { year: '1980'} })
```

Alternatively - you can use object destructuring

```js
this.setState(prevState => {
    ...prevState, 
    dob: { 
       ...prevState.dob, 
       year: '1980' 
    } 
})
```